# 17.10 upgrade: Drag & drop on touchpad doesn't work

Tags: touchpad, lenovo, 17.10

I have upgraded to 17.10 on my Lenovo Carbon X1 ver. 2. Suddenly the drag and drop doesn't work on the touchpad. It used to work on 17.04
I can drag and drop by using the double tap method (click and drag?) when holding down the tap, the second time, but I want the normal method to work also.

Strangely enough drag and drop works on the touchpad on rare occasions which I can't reproduce.

Comment: I have the same issue after upgrading to 18.04 on a Dell XPS L322X: double tapping and dragging works, but clicking and dragging stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue, and installing `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` did the trick (found it [here](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391695)).