# Cannot click and drag with touchpad after upgrade to 18.04

Tags: touchpad

I have just upgraded my Dell XPS L322X laptop from 16.04 to 18.04, and the behavior of my trackpad changed. Previously, I could drag to select text or move objects by clicking the left button of the pad and moving my finger. Now, I can only do so by tapping twice and moving. I do not know if tap-and-drag was working before.

I have looked at some configuration options available at [xinput](https://www.mankier.com/4/libinput) and at the [Synaptics driver](https://www.x.org/archive/X11R7.5/doc/man/man4/synaptics.4.html), but none of them seem to be related. In particular, disabling tap-and-drag does not make click-and-drag work.

This question reports a similar issue on 17.10: [17.10 upgrade: Drag & drop on touchpad doesn't work](https://askubuntu.com/questions/967741/17-10-upgrade-drag-drop-on-touchpad-doesnt-work).

There is a possibly related bug report on Launchpad: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/unity-greeter/+bug/1763209?comments=all.

Answer (score 1):

I was finally able to [find a solution](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2391695): installing the `xserver-xorg-input-synaptics` package made it all work; it even improved the sensibility of the trackpad.

Comment: I needed to install `xserver-xorg-input-all` as well in order for my keyboard to work after this.